# Merging Two Lists in Common Lisp

Tags: list, merge, lisp, common-lisp

Is there an efficient way to merge two lists in Lisp so that if they had common elements, those elements would be present in the resulting list only once?

At the moment, I have the following code:

```
(defun divisible-by-5 (num)
  (zerop (mod num 5)))

(defun divisible-by-3 (num)
  (zerop (mod num 3)))

(remove-if-not #'dividable-by-5 '(loop for i from 1 upto 10 collect i))
(remove-if-not #'divisible-by-3 '(loop for i from 1 upto 10 collect i))
```

I would like to merge the two lists returned by the bottom forms to be merged into on in a manner described above.

Comment: How about the function UNION ?

Comment: @sds That question is about how to implement your own `union` function instead of using the built-in function.

Comment: Why "divisible" **and** "dividable"?

Comment: @Barmar: you are right; however, this question carries no extra insight beyond one of the answers to that other question which mentions `union`.

Comment: Your lists are already sorted, you can call `merge` and remove values that are unique in a single pass (and keep only one of the duplicates).

Comment: I am new to lisp so I would appreciate any help. :)

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor I was using examples originally and just forgot to change the code before I copied from sketchbook.

Comment: I voted to reopen, since this is more specific than the standard UNION function;  this is about merging two lists that are already known to be sorted, and that are already guaranteed not to have duplicates.  (I didn't realize that the one reopen vote would open immediately, though. :/)

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor that's because you have gold [tag:common-lisp] badge. :)

Comment: @will I knew that could close with one vote,but I didn't know that it reopened with one

Answer (score 3):

You're already collecting the lists (1 ... n) twice, and then creating
new lists with certain elements removed, and then you're combining
those lists.  If you're looking for efficient, you should probably combine
the process of generating the initial list and testing and the collection:

```
(flet ((by-5 (n)
         (zerop (mod n 5)))
       (by-3 (n)
         (zerop (mod n 3))))
  (loop for x from 1 to 50
     unless (and (by-3 x)
                 (by-5 x))
     collect x))
```

But if you really want to collect the lists separately and then merge
them, you can do that with UNION:

```
(flet ((by-5 (n)
         (zerop (mod n 5)))
       (by-3 (n)
         (zerop (mod n 3))))
  (let ((fives (loop for x from 1 to 50 unless (by-5 x) collect x))
        (threes (loop for x from 1 to 50 unless (by-5 x) collect x)))
    (union fives threes)))
```

Now, union isn't guaranteed to preserve order, but in this case, since
you know that your lists are already ordered, you could merge them a
bit more efficiently, since you can compare the elements, and know
that after a certain point, you wouldn't encounter a duplicate:

```
(defun merge-unique (l1 l2 predicate)
  "Returns the result of merging L1 and L2, with no duplicates.
L1 and L2 should already be sets (that is, containing no duplicates), 
and should be ordered according to PREDICATE.  The tail of the result
may be shared with with either L1 or L2."
  (labels ((test (x y)
             (funcall predicate x y))
           (%merge (l1 l2 result)
             "Tail recursive merge procedure.  This could be converted
              to an iterative DO-loop without too much touble."
             (cond
               ((endp l1)
                (nreconc result l2))
               ((endp l2)
                (nreconc result l1))
               ((destructuring-bind (x . xs) l1
                  (destructuring-bind (y . ys) l2
                    (cond
                      ((test x y)
                       (%merge xs l2 (list* x result)))
                      ((test y x)
                       (%merge l1 ys (list* y result)))
                      (t
                       (%merge xs ys (list* x result))))))))))
    (%merge l1 l2 '())))
```

Here's an example of its use:

```
(merge-unique '(1 3 5 6) '(1 4 5 6) '<)
;;=> (1 3 4 5 6)
```

Comment: Does `merge-unique` require a special module? My CL says it is undefined.

Comment: @madphysicist It's not a library function. I just wrote it. The code for it is in the answer.

Comment: What does the last argument do and how do analyze it inside the function?

Comment: @Mad it's the predicate function used to check whether one element is less than another.  Since we're keeping the list sorted,  we know that if x < you, x comes first, or else if y < x, then y comes first, or else if neither x < y nor y < x, then they're equal, and only one of them should be included in the result (since we're eliminating duplicates).